# undefined function when passing navigation AND props to a react native component (basic disconnect button)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm a complete newbie and I'm trying to have a stack navigator only accessible if the user is logged, which works, but I can't manage to have a correctly working disconnect button.
I'm using a simple bool so far to grant access. The function used to disconnect, passed as a prop, is not found when I'm using the disconnect button.

App/Login screen :

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  const [userIsLogged, setUserLog] = useState(false);

  if (!userIsLogged) {
    return <LoginScreen setUserLog={setUserLog}/>;
  } else {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home">
            {props => <Home {...props} setUserLog={setUserLog}/>}
          </Stack.Screen>
          <Stack.Screen name="Rooms" component={Rooms}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

Where the disconnect button is called:

```
const Home = ({navigation}, props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Home</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.setUserLog(false)}>
        <Text>DISCONNECT</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Rooms')}>
        <Text>ACCESS TO ROOMS</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
};
```

(Code has been simplified heavily to only highlight my issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
const Home = ({navigation}, props) => {
```

to

```
const Home = (props) => {
const {navigation} = props;

return /* REST OF CODE */
```

`({navigation}, props)` doesn't split the props into two groups, it defines two arguments to your function. Which means props will always be `undefined` since you never pass a second argument in this case.

Comment: Thanks, this is it! Thanks for the explanation, it makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: @Ninotter No problem! Don't forget to mark this answer as solved! ;)